# Implementing redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, redux, persist

I'm trying to figure out how to configure redux persist in my application. I get a "'persistor' is not defined" in my react index.js file. I just need to persist a user_id so that when the page refreshes the data that is fetched on component did mount doesn't get lost.

this is my store.js file

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import userReducer from './reducers/userReducer';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    userReducer
});

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
  }
   
  const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
   
  export default () => {
    let store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware))
    let persistor = persistStore(store)
    return { store, persistor }
  }

//export default createStore(rootReducer,  applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware));
```

and this is my index.js file in my react app.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'



ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `store` you're importing is a function that should be fired to get the actual `store` along with the `persistor`.

Refactor your store import to look like this

```js
import useStore from './redux/store';


const { store, persistor } = useStore();
```

OR:

Refactor your `store.js` file

```js
let store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware));
let persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor }
```

And import it from your `index.js` file like this

```js
import { store, persistor } from './redux/store';
```